# permalink Issues in my .htaccess page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

Please give me a suggestion for my question.

when we set permalink in our site then the .htaccess code is

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

my site covert into  http to https and i am adding  below code to my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L,R=301]
```

These codes are to redirect when we using `www` or and `http` then automatically convert into `https:`

So my problem is when we add this code to my `.htaccess the post name or permalink is not working.`
home page was showing and also we can see the wp-admin pages, And all other links (example.www.xyz.com/register) not working.
What i do? Please give your valuable suggestions and answers.

Comment: Did you update the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" in the general settings in wordpress to include https?

Comment: yes  I am updates that all things...

Comment: When you say all other links are not working, do you mean they show a 404 page or they are staying http?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /documents/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax for your .htaccess - just replace domain.com with your actual website domain.

The first rewrite appends the www to all requests, the second rewrite appends the https to all requests.

Make sure to update your general settings in Wordpress as well, which you already commented that you did.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
```

Comment: When i use this code my site going to Redirect loop error

Comment: Is there anything else in the the access?

Comment: No the access is same